# How to Make Website Site visible over the internet on port 8080

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have IIS Installed on Azure VM with one Website running on PORT 80 which is exposed over the internet via the following Azure Firewall Role

if I try to bind incoming traffic on any other port that is not PORT 80, for some reason the Firewall doesn't seem to allow it.

for Example, if have a website running on PORT 8080 and I try to Set Firewall roles from EXTERNAL IP to the Internal IP via PORT 8080... the Website is unreachable. 
If the website runs on PORT 80 and the Firewall Role is via PORT 80.. than the site works.

does anyone have any idea/suggestions?

I would like to be able to Expose websites over the internet from the Same Web Server using different PORT for each one.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer to my problem via this URL:
https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2886/How-to-configure-IIS-to-access-website-using-IP-address.html

Basically After create Inbound Firewall Role from Azure on port 8080, the next step is to Add in Windows Firewall a New Role to allow Incoming HTTP traffic via port 8080 or any other port that the Wibsite is binding.

hope this will help others.